# Apache httpd.conf redirection. How to "balance" app

Tags: tomcat, redirect, mod-proxy, httpd.conf

This is probably a simple problem but I just can't seem to solve it! I have a website running 2 Apache Tomcats on different ports (e.g. 8080, 8085). However since my customers cannot access specific ports (their firewalls prevent this) they can only access my machine from port 80.

So I got the following redirects to work:

```
aServer.com/App1 redirects to aServer.com:8080/App1
aServer.com/App2 redirects to aServer.com:8085/App2
```

using the following httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass        /App1 http://<server ip address>:8080/App1
    ProxyPassReverse /App1 http://<server ip address>:8080/App1
    ProxyPass        /App2 http://<server ip address>:8085/App2
    ProxyPassReverse /App2 http://<server ip address>:8085/App2
</VirtualHost>
```

However if I want to deploy an application as a ROOT webapp in Tomcat, then I can't get the redirect to work properly. I modified httpd.conf to:

```
    ProxyPass        /App2 http://<server ip address>:8085
    ProxyPassReverse /App2 http://<server ip address>:8085
```

and now only the index.html page is returned and every dependency from the webpage (e.g. tomcat.css, tomcat.png) results in a not found error (
`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myServer/tomcat.css`)

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Unless you application explicitly supports proxies, you usually need to matching the proxy path with the context path.

`http://myserver/tomcat.css` is a request that will attempt to be fulfilled on your Apache document root since `/` is not being proxied to Tomcat. You'll need to do one of the following (options ranging from safe to lazy):

- proxy Apache root to the Tomcat root,
  *If you are not going to run both applications in the same container, make sure you put your ProxyPass directives in the correct order*
- modifiy the original `index.html` page in Tomcat to take into
  account the path change caused by the Proxy,
  *You'll have to redo this everytime you re-deploy.*
- provide a rewrite for ALL the resources to the proxied path
  *You'll have to redo this everytime a re-deploy changes the required resources.*